# Why do I get NameError: name 'as_completed' is not defined (I have from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor)

Tags: python, threadpoolexecutor

I have the following code:

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

```
def load_database():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(load_person, x) for x in range(max_people - 1)]
        for future in as_completed(futures):
            return(future.result()) 
        print(futures)
```

I am getting  "NameError: name 'as_completed' is not defined"

Do I need to import something else to use as_completed?

Thanks,
Chrissy

Comment: Did you also `from concurrent.futures import as_completed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`as_completed` lives in `concurrent.futures` so you'll need `from concurrent.futures import as_completed`